# python filter and sort list of orderedict from xml2dict

Tags: python, list, sorting, ordereddictionary

i have a question on sorting xml2dict outcome.
i have a xml like this:

Python 2.7

```
<schedule>
  <layout file="12" fromdt="2015-07-25 00:42:35" todt="2015-09-02 02:54:14" scheduleid="34" priority="0" dependents="30.jpg,38.mp4,39.mp4"/> 
  <layout file="10" fromdt="2015-08-25 00:42:32" todt="2015-09-02 02:54:03" scheduleid="34" priority="1" dependents="30.jpg,38.mp4,39.mp4"/> 
</schedule>
```

in which i use the following code to import to py:

```
dict_schedule_xml  = xmlFileToDict(filename)
layoutList.append(dict_schedule_xml['schedule']['layout'])
```

layoutList like below:

```
[[OrderedDict([(u'@file', u'12'), (u'@fromdt', u'2015-07-24 00:42:35'), (u'@todt', u'2015-09-02 02:54:14'), (u'@scheduleid', u'34'), (u'@priority', u'0'), (u'@dependents', u'30.jpg,38.mp4,39.mp4')]), OrderedDict([(u'@file', u'10'), (u'@fromdt', u'2015-08-25 00:42:32'), (u'@todt', u'2015-09-02 02:54:03'), (u'@scheduleid', u'34'), (u'@priority', u'1'), (u'@dependents', u'30.jpg,38.mp4,39.mp4')])]]
```

and i want to filter out some unwanted entry as execute follow:

```
dict_filtered_layout_list =  [s for s in layoutList if (onAirSchedule(s['@fromdt'],s['@todt']))]
dict_filtered_layout_list =  sorted(dict_filtered_layout_list, key=lambda k: k['@priority'], reverse = True)
```

using the following self-defined function:

```
 def onAirSchedule(fromdt, todt):
        dt_now = datetime.now()
        fromdt = datetime.strptime(fromdt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        todt   = datetime.strptime(todt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return (fromdt < dt_now < todt)
```

I wonder everytime i got the error

```
  File "xibo_reader.py", line 91, in on_modified
    dict_filtered_layout_list =  [s for s in layoutList if (onAirSchedule(s['@fromdt'],s['@todt']))]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I would like to have help on this as i don't know much on ordereddict behaviour...

Comment: can you show what `layoutList` looks like? And which like are you getting error on?

Comment: Updated, i hope you can find it more meaningful.

Comment: layouList looks like a list of list of OrderDicts , is there only one list inside? do you want dict_filtered_layout_list to be a list of orderedDicts ?

Comment: i want to be list if possible, but xmltodict translate it to ordereddict by default, and i am not sure how to handle ordereddict inside list, both approaches are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the update `layoutList` looks like a list of list of OrderedDict , so when you directly try to do `for s in layoutList if (onAirSchedule(s['@fromdt']` ,it causes error as lists cannot be accessed using string, only integer indexes.

If you want `dict_filtered_layout_list` to be a single list of OrderedDict with the filtered values, then you can iterate over the list of lists inside `layoutList` to create that single list.

Example -

```
dict_filtered_layout_list =  [s for list_orderedDict in layoutList for s in list_orderedDict if (onAirSchedule(s['@fromdt'],s['@todt']))]
dict_filtered_layout_list =  sorted(dict_filtered_layout_list, key=lambda k: k['@priority'], reverse = True)
```

Comment: Thanks and it works perfect !! thanks for your help Anand

Comment: Hi Anand, additional request, when i have one <layout> in <schedule> the function seems not working, would i know how to handle this? thanks.

Comment: when you have one `<layout>` what is returned in `layoutList` ?

Comment: [{"@file": "12", "@fromdt": "2015-08-20 01:00:01", "@todt": "2015-10-31 23:35:15", "@scheduleid": "35", "@priority": "111", "@dependents": "44.mp4,45.mp4,31.jpg,32.gif,33.png"}]

Comment: Then it seems like its an issue with xmlFiletoDict function, or whatever returns the layoutList, you should ask them to consistently return either a list of list of ordereddict or a list of ordereddict, not both of them.

Comment: If i have one layout only, how can i become list of list of ordereddict? please advice and million thanks       `def xmlFileToDict(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        xml = f.read()
    return (xmltodict.parse(xml))`